# PHP file_get_contents failed to open multiple stream

Tags: php, file, download, file-get-contents

I am working on a php script that is supposed to use the file_get_contents function.

When I use it in my script just once it works fantastic and I don't get any error but if I implement it more then once I get the following error:

> "https://engine.sighten.io/api/ops/download_from_remote/1644d83f-675b-42f9-a8cc-b2cb63d9c705/):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST".

Here are the details:

1. The webhook I receive is something like this:

> ```
>  {  
>     "owned_by_user":{  
>        "link":"",
>        "uuid":"ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5",
>        "natural_id":"jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com"
>     },
>     "date_completed":"None",
>     "date_created":"2017-08-16T12:47:17.700198+00:00",
>     "date_started":"None",
>     "milestone":{  
>        "link":"/api/solar/milestone/eb8fad9a-47cf-448a-920d-9a4d35b3ea39",
>        "uuid":"eb8fad9a-47cf-448a-920d-9a4d35b3ea39",
>        "natural_id":"API TEST 1 Test Ignore//Cash // Sales Requirements"
>     },
>     "natural_id":"Installation Agreement",
>     "status":"SIGN",
>     "created_by":{  
>        "link":"",
>        "uuid":"ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5",
>        "natural_id":"jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com"
>     },
>     "documents":[  
>        {  
>           "owned_by_user":{  
>
>           },
>           "date_created":"2017-08-16T12:49:49.245223+00:00",
>           "created_by":{  
>
>           },
>           "download_url":"/api/ops/download_from_remote/69c6a394-310a-4300-a18b-7544edfa28a9/",
>           "modified_by":{  
>
>           },
>           "uuid":"69c6a394-310a-4300-a18b-7544edfa28a9",
>           "description":"Sun Us Solar Agreement v3.pdf",
>           "natural_id":"Sun Us Solar Agreement v3.pdf",
>           "date_updated":"2017-08-16T12:49:49.245248+00:00",
>           "owned_by_organization":{  
>
>           },
>           "remote_host":"AMZ",
>           "name":"Sun Us Solar Agreement v3.pdf",
>           "merged_doc":true
>        },
>        {  
>           "owned_by_user":{  
>
>           },
>           "date_created":"2017-08-16T12:49:54.873908+00:00",
>           "created_by":{  
>
>           },
>           "download_url":"/api/ops/download_from_remote/7737b88f-0dec-4917-bf73-aa52e3c5e6ab/",
>           "modified_by":{  
>
>           },
>           "uuid":"7737b88f-0dec-4917-bf73-aa52e3c5e6ab",
>           "description":"Sun Us Solar Agreement v3.pdf",
>           "natural_id":"Sun Us Solar Agreement v3.pdf",
>           "date_updated":"2017-08-16T12:49:54.873936+00:00",
>           "owned_by_organization":{  
>
>           },
>           "remote_host":"AMZ",
>           "name":"Sun Us Solar Agreement v3.pdf",
>           "merged_doc":true
>        },
>        {  
>           "owned_by_user":{  
>              "link":"",
>              "uuid":"ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5",
>              "natural_id":"jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com"
>           },
>           "date_created":"2017-08-16T13:03:42.708770+00:00",
>           "created_by":{  
>              "link":"",
>              "uuid":"ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5",
>              "natural_id":"jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com"
>           },
>           "download_url":"/api/ops/download_from_remote/1644d83f-675b-42f9-a8cc-b2cb63d9c705/",
>           "modified_by":{  
>              "link":"",
>              "uuid":"ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5",
>              "natural_id":"jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com"
>           },
>           "uuid":"1644d83f-675b-42f9-a8cc-b2cb63d9c705",
>           "description":"Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone.pdf",
>           "natural_id":"Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone.pdf",
>           "date_updated":"2017-08-16T13:03:42.708799+00:00",
>           "owned_by_organization":{  
>              "link":"",
>              "uuid":"e62239df-7f3a-4ead-b4cd-500541f8b094",
>              "natural_id":"Sunus Solar"
>           },
>           "remote_host":"AMZ",
>           "name":"Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone.pdf",
>           "merged_doc":true
>        }
>     ],
>     "modified_by":{  
>        "link":"",
>        "uuid":"ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5",
>        "natural_id":"jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com"
>     },
>     "uuid":"411143d0-ecde-429d-943f-d4f22f12c87c",
>     "type":"DOC",
>     "assigned_to":{  
>        "link":"",
>        "uuid":"ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5",
>        "natural_id":"jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com"
>     },
>     "date_updated":"2017-08-16 13:03:42.768407+00:00",
>     "date_approved":"None",
>     "owned_by_organization":{  
>        "link":"",
>        "uuid":"e62239df-7f3a-4ead-b4cd-500541f8b094",
>        "natural_id":"Sunus Solar"
>     },
>     "comments":[  
>
>     ],
>     "site_id":"ac396b97-b22a-4914-9a0f-dbbda61116eb",
>     "name":"Installation Agreement"  }
> ```

2. The php code part, which makes the download:

```
foreach($documents as &$document) {
    $downloadlink = $document['download_url'];
    $downloadname = $document['name'];
    $remote_url = 'https://engine.sighten.io' . $downloadlink;
    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => "GET",
            'header' => "Authorization: Token cd048c7b0a127d876e5481ccbd0beb1566bebea2"
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $file = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);
    $download = file_put_contents($downloadname, $file);
}
```

3. As you can see the json file contains 2 links/files. The script work well in case of the first file, I can download on my server, but in case of second file I get the above mentioned error. I have checked and the `$remote_url` variable contains the correct URL of the files.

CLARIFICATION:

When I execute the script I see the following
[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwmIo.png)

The problem is that the second file has no content. Please note, that I have executed the script once again, with other files so the json in this case was the following:

```
{"date_created": "2017-08-16T15:10:19.327922+00:00", "status": "SIGN", "owned_by_user": {"link": "", "natural_id": "jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com", "uuid": "ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5"}, "documents": [{"download_url": "/api/ops/download_from_remote/b608171b-4cd3-4b2a-bef0-19635b00ed52/", "merged_doc": true, "owned_by_user": {}, "date_updated": "2017-08-16T15:10:45.039007+00:00", "uuid": "b608171b-4cd3-4b2a-bef0-19635b00ed52", "remote_host": "AMZ", "description": "Sun Us Solar Agreement v3.pdf", "created_by": {}, "date_created": "2017-08-16T15:10:45.038979+00:00", "modified_by": {}, "owned_by_organization": {}, "name": "Sun Us Solar Agreement v3.pdf", "natural_id": "Sun Us Solar Agreement v3.pdf"}, {"download_url": "/api/ops/download_from_remote/049957a5-1340-4e47-bfa2-3e4832d8b88f/", "merged_doc": true, "owned_by_user": {"link": "", "natural_id": "jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com", "uuid": "ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5"}, "date_updated": "2017-08-16T15:17:21.529021+00:00", "uuid": "049957a5-1340-4e47-bfa2-3e4832d8b88f", "remote_host": "AMZ", "description": "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone.pdf", "created_by": {"link": "", "natural_id": "jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com", "uuid": "ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5"}, "date_created": "2017-08-16T15:17:21.528992+00:00", "modified_by": {"link": "", "natural_id": "jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com", "uuid": "ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5"}, "owned_by_organization": {"link": "", "natural_id": "Sunus Solar", "uuid": "e62239df-7f3a-4ead-b4cd-500541f8b094"}, "name": "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone.pdf", "natural_id": "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone.pdf"}], "date_updated": "2017-08-16 15:17:21.584150+00:00", "date_approved": "None", "modified_by": {"link": "", "natural_id": "jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com", "uuid": "ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5"}, "type": "DOC", "created_by": {"link": "", "natural_id": "jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com", "uuid": "ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5"}, "comments": [], "uuid": "0f94a08f-4f06-444c-babe-f32ed059a88f", "assigned_to": {"link": "", "natural_id": "jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com", "uuid": "ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5"}, "owned_by_organization": {"link": "", "natural_id": "Sunus Solar", "uuid": "e62239df-7f3a-4ead-b4cd-500541f8b094"}, "date_started": "None", "name": "Installation Agreement", "date_completed": "None", "natural_id": "Installation Agreement", "milestone": {"link": "/api/solar/milestone/1b599fcd-448f-4444-a636-1ae931f25461", "natural_id": "API TEST 1 Test Ignore//Cash // Sales Requirements", "uuid": "1b599fcd-448f-4444-a636-1ae931f25461"}, "site_id": "c2504124-55e4-43b5-9a0c-370ec494d887"}
```

Comment: why the & in the foreach line?

Comment: I see 3 not 2 links in the json? But is the problem downloading twice or is the problem the second link? Did you try to skip the first one and only donwload no 2 and 3?

Comment: the first and second try to write the same output filename. That is usually allowed, but not always. Apart from that: the first document seems to be a word file: you write is as a .pdf filename

Comment: 1. why the & in the foreach line? - it's just a mistake, I post this question from my phone, in the php script no &

Comment: 2. You have right, the given json example contains 3 links, but anyway the problem is that I can download just the first one

Comment: 3. I have tried with .pdf file too. The same result.

Comment: I have added a screenshot with some clarification. Maybe this will help you understanding my problem.

Comment: so the file with a ' in the name has size 0. check the size of $file just before you write it to disk. Is it a writing issue, or reading it from the url?

Comment: again: for me it is working, using most of your script. `length($file); ` gives me `260027` `260027` and `1082762`

Comment: It's a reading issue. For me the file size is 0. I think you have hardcoded the URL. Correct?

Comment: If I do so, it's working for me too. But when I use this line $remote_url = 'https://engine.sighten.io'.$downloadlink; and not this $remote_url = 'https://engine.sighten.io/api/ops/download_from_remote/b98c9831-c2c2-4a15-902c-4e86c7bc30cc/'; I got the error message. I have checked the $remote_url variable and contains a valid download URL. Furthermore in case of the first file working well.

Comment: I have tried with unset($remote_url) too, so the script has rebuilt this variable. I put this line just before the } in the foreach. Doesn't help. Any other idea?

Comment: I copied your script as it was before you outlined it as code. I read the json as `$j = json_decode($var);` And then `$documents = $j->documents;` AFterwards I need to use `$document->download_url; ` rather than your array version of it. I do not write it to file, but just dump the length of the found $file;

Comment: I will place my working script in an answer below, so you can compare.

Answer (score 0):

i can't access your request link because i don't have an API key,

> When I use it in my script just once it works fantastic and I don't get any error but if I implement it more then once I get an error

Are you sure you got one that doesn't have API limitations (like one request a second)?

file_get_contents and file_put_content sometimes say synchronously they finished their jobs when in fact the hard disk is still writing content, i had a similar issue and i figured out it worked if i called the function twice but with a 4s sleep inbetween

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you, but in my case the sleep function doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This script is working for me. It does not save to file, as discussion above revealed TS cannot read the 3rd file and so it would not be the problem here

at the end of the foreach-loop some vars are dumped to screen for debugging purposes.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);

$d = '{"owned_by_user": {"link": "", "uuid": "ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5", "natural_id": "jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com"}, "date_completed": "None", "date_created": "2017-08-16T12:47:17.700198+00:00", "date_started": "None", "milestone": {"link": "/api/solar/milestone/eb8fad9a-47cf-448a-920d-9a4d35b3ea39", "uuid": "eb8fad9a-47cf-448a-920d-9a4d35b3ea39", "natural_id": "API TEST 1 Test Ignore//Cash // Sales Requirements"}, "natural_id": "Installation Agreement", "status": "SIGN", "created_by": {"link": "", "uuid": "ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5", "natural_id": "jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com"}, "documents": [{"owned_by_user": {}, "date_created": "2017-08-16T12:49:49.245223+00:00", "created_by": {}, "download_url": "/api/ops/download_from_remote/69c6a394-310a-4300-a18b-7544edfa28a9/", "modified_by": {}, "uuid": "69c6a394-310a-4300-a18b-7544edfa28a9", "description": "Sun Us Solar Agreement v3.pdf", "natural_id": "Sun Us Solar Agreement v3.pdf", "date_updated": "2017-08-16T12:49:49.245248+00:00", "owned_by_organization": {}, "remote_host": "AMZ", "name": "Sun Us Solar Agreement v3.pdf", "merged_doc": true}, {"owned_by_user": {}, "date_created": "2017-08-16T12:49:54.873908+00:00", "created_by": {}, "download_url": "/api/ops/download_from_remote/7737b88f-0dec-4917-bf73-aa52e3c5e6ab/", "modified_by": {}, "uuid": "7737b88f-0dec-4917-bf73-aa52e3c5e6ab", "description": "Sun Us Solar Agreement v3.pdf", "natural_id": "Sun Us Solar Agreement v3.pdf", "date_updated": "2017-08-16T12:49:54.873936+00:00", "owned_by_organization": {}, "remote_host": "AMZ", "name": "Sun Us Solar Agreement v3.pdf", "merged_doc": true}, {"owned_by_user": {"link": "", "uuid": "ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5", "natural_id": "jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com"}, "date_created": "2017-08-16T13:03:42.708770+00:00", "created_by": {"link": "", "uuid": "ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5", "natural_id": "jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com"}, "download_url":"/api/ops/download_from_remote/1644d83f-675b-42f9-a8cc-b2cb63d9c705/", "modified_by": {"link": "", "uuid": "ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5", "natural_id": "jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com"}, "uuid": "1644d83f-675b-42f9-a8cc-b2cb63d9c705", "description": "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer\'s Stone.pdf", "natural_id": "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer\'s Stone.pdf", "date_updated": "2017-08-16T13:03:42.708799+00:00", "owned_by_organization": {"link": "", "uuid": "e62239df-7f3a-4ead-b4cd-500541f8b094", "natural_id": "Sunus Solar"}, "remote_host": "AMZ", "name": "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer\'s Stone.pdf", "merged_doc": true}], "modified_by": {"link": "", "uuid": "ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5", "natural_id": "jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com"}, "uuid": "411143d0-ecde-429d-943f-d4f22f12c87c", "type": "DOC", "assigned_to": {"link": "", "uuid": "ec5aec48-621e-4cd6-a029-d5da1a9a18d5", "natural_id": "jbantock@catalystgroupdevelopment.com"}, "date_updated": "2017-08-16 13:03:42.768407+00:00", "date_approved": "None", "owned_by_organization": {"link": "", "uuid": "e62239df-7f3a-4ead-b4cd-500541f8b094", "natural_id": "Sunus Solar"}, "comments": [], "site_id": "ac396b97-b22a-4914-9a0f-dbbda61116eb", "name": "Installation Agreement"}';

$documents = json_decode($d);
$documents = $documents->documents;


foreach($documents as $document) {

    $downloadlink = $document->download_url;
    $downloadname = $document->name;
    $remote_url = 'https://engine.sighten.io' . $downloadlink;
    $opts = array('http' => array('method' => "GET", 'header' => "Authorization: Token cd048c7b0a127d876e5481ccbd0beb1566bebea2"
        ));
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $file = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);
    $size = strlen($file);
    if(1) {
        echo 'on line: ' . __LINE__ . ' in file ' . __FILE__;
        printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($document->download_url, 1));
        printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($downloadname, 1));
        printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($size, 1));
    }

} ?>
```

Are you sure you send the Auth code along in your real script?